# Не корректная работа jquery плагина chosen.jquery.js при использовании метода clone

Tags: jquery

При создании копии элементов с использованием метода `clone(true)`, перестает корректно работать `chosen.jquery.js` для копируемого элемента.

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблем или знает причину всего этого?

Пример кода:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.add_study_wc', function() {
    var elem = $(this).closest('.class_education_wc');
    elem.clone(true).insertAfter(elem);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="get" name="estimation_of_chances" id="estimation_of_chances">
  <fieldset id="education">
    <legend>Образование</legend>

    <div class="class_education_wc clearfix">
      <div class="elem_form clearfix">
        <label for="level">Уровень</label>
        <select name="level" id="level" class="chosen">
          <option value="1">Высшее</option>
          <option value="2">Бакалавр</option>
          <option value="3">Магистр</option>
          <option value="4">Кандидат наук </option>
          <option value="5">Доктор наук </option>
          <option value="6">Неоконченное высшее</option>
          <option value="7">Средне специальное </option>
          <option value="8">Среднее</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="years clearfix clearfix">
        <label for="years_of_study">Годы учебы</label>
        <select name="years_of_study" id="years_of_study" class="chosen">
          <option value="1">1988</option>
          <option value="2">1989</option>
          <option value="3">2000</option>
          <option value="4">2001</option>
        </select>
        <select name="end_years_of_study" id="end_years_of_study" class="chosen">
          <option value="1">1988</option>
          <option value="2">1989</option>
          <option value="3">2000</option>
          <option value="4">2001</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <span class="add_study_wc add_more">Добавить еще одно место обучения</span>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что в новом элементе chosen вообще не работает?

Обычно такого рода плагины проходят по коду один раз в момент подключения, и не следят в дальнейшем за его изменениями. Плагину просто неоткуда знать, что он теперь должен обрабатывать ещё и вновь созданный селект.

Инициализируйте плагин заново на новом элементе после его создания.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но  это не помогает, при клике на вновь созданный элемент в работу включается основной селект, с которого начиналось копирование, и так с каждым вновь скопированным элементом.

Comment: ну тогда ссылку на страницу в студию.

Comment: http://www.svarock.webcapitan.com/test/test.html